# Potential for optimizing sets for state space enumeration in Haskell based on heap profile?

Tags: optimization, haskell, profile

I wrote a small state space explorer for an exhaustive search problem. Given a start state, a transition relation computes a set of successor states, until all states have been seen (I know that the search space is finite). For my problem at hand, it yields 2*n successor states tops. For all states, I also check if they satisfy some property `dlCheck` (here, there's only ONE matching state in the whole state space).

As I keep the `Data.Set` of seen states around, I'm expecting big-time memory consumption already. However, the heap profile has me puzzling (ATest contains the code below, the property check and transition are in another module):
[image: heap profile] [image: Set profile]

If I would guess, I'd say that lower bound on `Set` is the size of the already explored state space. *I am wondering where the periodic contraction is coming from.* Do you spot anything funny in the exploration below? The main call is into the final `dlsStreamHist` at the bottom.

Given that the whole program is too large to post, and I have some idea on the performance of the transition relation and the property check, I'm assuming the problem is somewhere here. Am I maybe looking for strict set-operations, very much like `foldl'`? It could be that somehow first all successor states are calculated, before comparing them to the `seen` set, instead of doing it on the fly.

```
-- 'test' applies a step to each process in the state (individually), yielding a set of successor states
-- ...or not, if a process blocks. Already seen states are in the first component
-- so that we don't explore them again,
-- blocked configs go into the second, and new successor states go into the third component.
-- We produce a potentially infinite stream of sets of blocked/enabled configurations.
-- This method generates our search space; the transition relation 'step' is in here.
testHistory :: State a => Set a -> Set a -> [(Set a, Set a, Set a)]
testHistory seen ps
  | null ps = []
  | otherwise = let (ls,rs) = fold (\s lr -> fold (\x (l,r) -> maybe (insert s l,r)
                                                                     (\c -> (l,insert c r)) x) lr (step s)) (empty,empty) ps
                    newSeen = seen `union` ps
                    new = rs `difference` newSeen
                    in (newSeen,ls,new):(testHistory newSeen new)

-- Take a program, and run it (to infinity). For each blocked configuration, collect all deadlocks (if any).
-- For infinite streams, you might want to 'nub' the result.
dlsStreamT :: State a => (Set a -> [(Set a, c)]) -> a -> [Set (Process,Lock,Int)]
dlsStreamT testF p = concatMap (Data.Set.toList . (fold (union) empty) . (filter (not . null)) . (Data.Set.map (filter (not . null)))) $ map ((filter (not . null)) . (Data.Set.map dlCheck) . fst) (testF (singleton p))
dlsStreamHist :: State a => a -> [Set (Process,Lock,Int)]
dlsStreamHist = dlsStreamT (map (\(_,x,y)->(x,y)) . testHistory empty)
```

Comment: Is there a periodic contraction in `Set`?  I can't tell from that profile.

Comment: @augustss: I don't expect the peaks being so high. But maybe I'm misinterpreting the graph. Given that I keep track of all states anyway, after classifying a state as `new` or `seen`, in the latter state I don't expect it to hang around until this iteration is completed.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi Could you profile with -hySet?

Comment: @augustss: That doesn't seem to generate any profiling output at all?! (no `.hp`-file).

Comment: @ShiDoiSi You probably need -h as well.

Comment: @augustss: Thanks, that helped; additional figure now uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it's having to construct the whole set of new states before it can complete each testHistory step: you can't calculate  `` rs `difference` newSeen `` until you've constructed all of `newSeen` for instance (for hopefully obvious reasons).

Then I'd guess that the filtering by `dlCheck` is lazy, so it's building up a pile of thunks before evaluating them all, leading to the pulsating heap usage. Is there some reason you can't fold the `dlCheck` into the state generation so that you can apply it to states as they're generated?

NB, what process algebra are you using? (Not that it's relevant, it just happens to be my field!)

Comment: Hm, I don't follow your argument about having to compute `newSeen`: once an element shows up in `newSeen`, I can immediately remove it from `rs`.

We're doing a simple home-grown thing that we couldn't be bothered with to encode in CSP ;)

Comment: Hmm. You're right that the construction of newSeen is purely additive: I misread the code. What about rs?

Comment: `rs` coming from the `let` is also additive, I'd say. And of course both `newSeen` and `rs` are blocking `new`.